# How to setup the 3dots menu inside Image.network in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm looking an example to implement the 3 dots menu inside a picture on my feed of my app... any ideas?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EROqx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example in the question is not to use an icon in the photo. Like this:

```
       Column(
                children: [
                  Row(children: [...,Icon()],),
                  Image.network(),
                ],
              )
```

But if you want to use icon in the photo, you can use `Stack`. Like this:

```
Container(
          height: 250,
          width: 250,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Image.network(
                  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.more_horiz,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

Comment: Hello and Thank you for your answer Zeed!! It's posible to use this Stack with the 3 dots?,Regards!

Comment: The sample code I wrote does exactly that. You can copy paste it under the `Scaffold`